# What is the time complexity of std::string::compare() in C++ function in C++?

Tags: c++, string-comparison

What will be the time complexity of **std::string::compare()** in C++?

---

For example, if we have to check if the given input matches our required string or not -

let say if we are taking origin as an input where Origin can be INDIAN or NON_INDIAN, we can do

1.

```
if(origin == "INDIAN"){
    // our code
}
```

OR

2.

```
if(!origin.compare("INDIAN")){
    // our code
}
```

---

The first method takes O(1) time, right?

So I am wondering, How much time that compare function might be taking!
**Can anyone help me clear my doubt?**

Comment: both are `O(first-character-that-mismatches)`

Comment: Yep.  WOI if bot standardized.  Assume std string is a decent SBO/heap string; like, 80%+ optimal.  Repeated assignment might not be optimal for your use (which is better, swapping or reusing buffer?  Is situation specific, snd IIRC the standard leaves the decision up to the library)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I didn't understood, can you elaborate/simplify your explanation?

Comment: Why do you think the first one would be O(1)? How can you compare strings of arbitrary length in constant time? It will (until C++ 20) call `std::string::operator=` which most likely uses `std::string::compare` internally.

Comment: `std::string` might check string lengths up front, which usually is an O(1) check and sufficient here. However, if `std::string` needs to call `strlen` for that, it is no longer O(1). In this case, the argument is a `const char[7]` so there's no real need for `strlen`.